# I don't see an option to partition my drive in a Bootcamp.

Tags: boot-camp, imac

I don't see an option to partition my drive in a Bootcamp. It shows me only options to Download windows Support  and Install Windows 7 or later.

iMac Mid 2011

Comment: You have installed Bootcamp correct?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, the partitioning option/window appears *after* the window you are in. In order to install Windows:

1. Open up Bootcamp Assistant. You will first need to get the support drivers, so tick the box for it.
2. In most cases, you'll want to create a bootable USB drive (or something similar), so tick the box if it appears. (Probably not needed if you have a disc, and your Mac has a DVD/CD slot)
3. If you've selected the bootable USB drive, it'll ask you for the ISO image, select it, and then choose a USB drive.
4. You'll need to follow the instructions for getting the Windows support drivers, so do it and continue on to the next step. (I don't think they are absolutely necessary in order to start using Windows, but I'd suggest sticking to Apple's drivers)
5. You will see the partitioning window. This is where you can either manually drag to reach the space you need, or press Divide Equally to make Windows and OSX take the amount of space.
6. The reset should be the general Windows installation. Follow that, and install the support drivers you downloaded previously.

For more information follow Apple's support site. Assuming you run Mavericks or later, follow this article:
https://help.apple.com/bootcamp/mac/5.0/help/
If not, then you could either find the correct article. (Or follow it anyways, I don't think it's too much changed)